# Can I use variables in UiBinder style definitions in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder

In the following example, from a file MessageView.ui.xml:

```
<ui:style>
    .polite {
      position:fixed;
      background-color:notice-background-color;
      top:1em;
      left:2em;
      white-space:nowrap;
      border-radius:.5em;}
</ui:style>

<g:PopupPanel styleName="{style.polite}">
    <g:HTML ui:field="message">Message goes here.</g:HTML>
</g:PopupPanel>
```

can I define @notice-background-color such that other UiBinder files can also use the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Define your color as static `String`:

```
package com.myproject.client.resource;

public class MyColors {
    public static String lightGreen = "#0bdc1a";
}
```

And define an `@eval` variable:

```
<ui:style>
    @eval notice-background-color com.myproject.client.resource.MyColors.lightGreen;

    .polite {
      position:fixed;
      background-color:notice-background-color;
      top:1em;
      left:2em;
      white-space:nowrap;
      border-radius:.5em;}
</ui:style>

<g:PopupPanel styleName="{style.polite}">
    <g:HTML ui:field="message">Message goes here.</g:HTML>
</g:PopupPanel>
```

Comment: This should do the trick, and here is a reference: https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/CssResource#Constants

Comment: that's great. I'll implement this tomorrow. Do you know who I can access this .lightGreen from my general .css file too? I'd then have all such definitions defined in one place.

Comment: great. and the same approach can be used in the app's .css file. In the .css file add the same @eval before using lightGreen in a css definition.